# Related link for the device viewing

Tags: php, android, ios, device

I'm wanting to add content to [my site](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2) with the same layout as it currently is.

Basically, you can see a list of categories on my home page. This then links to my list.php page with the content to reflect the title.

I'm looking for the same thing but what I'm wanting is for it to display apps.php instead of list.php which does the same thing but instead of the content categorised by type I have them categorised by device. For example apps.php?id=iphone.

What I am wanting is a link on my index page to be displayed to this apps.php page if they are using the related devices.

For example

The link with title "app download" will be displayed on an iPhone/iPod touch with the link to apps.php?id=iphone, the androids link will be apps.php?id=android and the same for iPad mini and iPad but nothing will be displayed on other devices.

Please can someone guide me on how to do this. Thanks.

I'm guessing it can be done with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bodyclass ='desktop';
if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
   bodyclass = 'android';
} else if((window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone'))||(window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPod'))) {
  bodyclass = 'iphone';
} else if (window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPad')){
  bodyclass = 'ipad';
}
window.onload = function(){
  document.body.className += ' '+ bodyclass;
} 
<script>
```

And

```
<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button iphone"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=iPhone' " type="submit" /></li></ul>

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button ipad"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=iPad' " type="submit" /></li></ul> 

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button android"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=android' " type="submit" /></li></ul>
```

But they do not seem to work.

**Update:**

If you have a look at [THIS PICTURE](http://xclo.mobi/xclo2/image.jpg) taken on my iPad just now you will see 3 app downloads buttons. The top One links to app.php?id=android the middle one links to app.php?id=iphone and the bottom one links to app.php?id=ipad. Obviously on this occasion only the 3rd link should be visible and the other 2hidden as I am viewing on my iPad.

If I was to view on my iPod touch then only the middle one should be visible.

My code for the index.php page in the screenshot is this:

```
<?PHP 
include_once('include/connection.php'); 
include_once('include/article.php');

$category = new category;
$articles = $category->fetch_all();


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR...nsitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Xclo.mobi</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="homescreen.png" />
<link href="startup.png" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var bodyclass ='desktop';
if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('android') != null) ) {
   bodyclass = 'android';
} else if((window.navigator.userAgent.match('iphone') != null)||(window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPod') != null)) {
  bodyclass = 'iphone';
} else if (window.navigator.userAgent.match('ipad') != null){
  bodyclass = 'ipad';
}
window.onload = function(){
  document.body.className += ' '+ bodyclass;
} 
<script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-34172259-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xclo.co.uk']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>


<div id="content">

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button android"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=android' " type="submit" /></li></ul>

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button iphone"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=iphone' " type="submit" /></li></ul>

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button ipad"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=ipad' " type="submit" /></li></ul>


<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button"> 
<a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>"/>
</a></li></ul>
<?php } ?>




</div>
<br><center>
<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ws-eu.amazon-...d9-6cf16307e855"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws-eu.amazon-...t">Amazon.co.uk Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT></center>

<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work please. Thank you.

Comment: so you want something like this: if somebody comes to your mobile site with an android device, the app download link have this: apps.php?id=android ? Am I right?

Comment: Hi. Yes you are exactly right. The same goes for iPhone/iPod touch for ?id=iPhone and iPad mini and iPad ?id=iPad cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the OS with these in PHP: [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) or [`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
If you want to know, what user agent gives for you, when an android or iPhone user visit your web page, visit [this](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/os) and select that OS which want you to see.

You can that string split, or search on it, it's your choice what you choose. (maybe the `get_browser(NULL, true)` is better choice.

If you get the OS, use an if, and print that code which is for that OS.

Edit:
Changes these:
From:

```
var bodyclass ='desktop';
if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('android') != null) ) {
   bodyclass = 'android';
} else if((window.navigator.userAgent.match('iphone') != null)) {
  bodyclass = 'iphone';
} else if (window.navigator.userAgent.match('ipad') != null){
  bodyclass = 'ipad';
}
window.onload = function(){
  document.body.className += ' '+ bodyclass;
} 

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button android"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=android' " type="submit" /></li></ul>

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button iphone"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=iphone' " type="submit" /></li></ul>

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button ipad"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=ipad' " type="submit" /></li></ul>
```

To:

```
var bodyclass ='desktop';
if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
   bodyclass = 'android';
} else if((window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1)) {
  bodyclass = 'iphone';
} else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1){
  bodyclass = 'ipad';
}
window.onload = function(){
  if(bodyclass != "desktop") document.getElementById(bodyclass).style.display="";
  document.body.className += ' '+ bodyclass;
} 

<ul class="pageitem" id="android" style="display:none;"><li class="button android"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=android' " type="submit" /></li></ul>

<ul class="pageitem" id="iphone" style="display:none;"><li class="button iphone"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=iphone' " type="submit" /></li></ul>

<ul class="pageitem" id="ipad" style="display:none;"><li class="button ipad"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=ipad' " type="submit" /></li></ul>
```

Comment: I've added some codes above. They just do not seem to work. Please can you tell me why. Thanks,

Comment: you need to use like this: `window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone') != null` of course, at iPhone and iPad, the Android is good. So you have 3 errors

Comment: oh, and the iPad case never will used, because the iPhone has been true, it won't going forth, it'll stopped there.

Comment: On my iPad with your code, NONE of them display at all. Is there another way? Thanks

Comment: Hi. I have sorted this. Using my answer. please 1up my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I edited, there was a problem with mach() because its only give back something if the FULL line match and it's case sensitive the indexOf() so we needed to write the P and A with upper case...

Comment: ah, and now, if you visit your site with windows, you can see a app download button, with no id

Comment: Ah. I have only checked on my iPad and iPod touch. Is there an else hide function I can use?

Comment: I rewrite the code, which was wrong, an I tested in firebug, so now it need to works the basic mechanic for this is: everything hide, which you don't need always, and show that elements, which you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.

By using this code:

```
>      <?php $ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; switch(true) {   case
>       stripos($ua,'android') :
>        $device = 'android'; break;   case stripos($ua,'ipad') :
>         $device = 'ipad'; break;   case stripos($ua,'iphone') :
>         $device = 'iphone'; break; } ?>  
> 
> <ul class="pageitem"><li class="button android"><input name="Submit"
> value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=<?php echo
> $device; ?>' "
>          type="submit" /></li></ul>
```

Thank you. Please 1up.